# Qual o erro nesse Código:

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou tentando compilar esse código,do use a cabeça C mas esta me retornando erros

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void go_south_east(int* lat, int* lon)
    {
        *lat = *lat -1;
        *lon = *lon - 1;

    }

    int main()
    {
        int latitude = 32;
        int logitude = -64;
        go_south_east(&latitude, &longitude);
        printf("Avast! Now at: [%i, %i]\n", latitude, longitude);
      return 0;

    }
```

Error:

```
root@kali:~# gcc testmains.c -o testmains testmains.c: In function ‘main’: testmains.c:14:28: error: ‘longitude’ undeclared (first use in this function) testmains.c:14:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Poderia esclarecer qual é a sua dúvida?  Que erro o compilador está retornando? Aproveite e faça um [tour] pelo site e confira o guia de [ask].

Comment: Qual erro você está tendo exatamente?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao stackoverflow em Português! Tente explicar melhor o seu problema, o erro que lhe ocorre e o que pretende fazer, assim fica difícil alguém responder...

Comment: Nossa, porque negativaram?

Comment: Bom, eu não negativei, mas acredito que foi por que não está claro o que você está perguntando. A situação pode ser revertida facilmente, não precisa se preocupar. Comece por esclarecer sua dúvida: qual erro está tendo? O que espera que aconteça de verdade no seu código?

Comment: root@kali:~# gcc testmains.c -o testmains
testmains.c: In function ‘main’:
testmains.c:14:28: error: ‘longitude’ undeclared (first use in this function)
testmains.c:14:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: Talvez você prefira [edit] sua pergunta para adicionar o erro, fica mais claro para ler.

Comment: Você declarou "logitude" (sic). Foi um simples erro de digitação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, corrige o nome da variável :

```
int logitude = -64;
go_south_east(&latitude, &longitude);
```

Quando esta declarando está faltando um 'n' no longitude.

Comment: Eu sou burro demais para perceber erros de digitação......

Comment: Use uma IDE para reduzir a chance desses erros acontecerem :)

Answer (score 9):

Em um [teste rápido](http://ideone.com/5rxUwJ) observa-se as seguinte mensagens de erro:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:14:35: error: ‘longitude’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         go_south_east(&latitude, &longitude);
                                   ^
prog.c:14:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
prog.c:13:13: warning: unused variable ‘logitude’ [-Wunused-variable]
         int logitude = -64;
         ^
```

Ou seja, a variável `longitude`não foi declarada, e temos uma outra variável `logitude` que não é utilizada.

Imagino que você simplesmente escreveu errado o nome desta variável. [Corrigindo isso](http://ideone.com/GAae7e) o código compila e executa.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo compilar....

Comment: Se você prestar atenção às mensagens de erro e os avisos do compilador você consegue descobrir rapidinho qual é o problema.